# Oracle + PHP : Display results in HTML Table

Tags: php, html, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm having a little trouble tinkering with PHP and Oracle using OCI8 to connect.  I've confirmed that i'm able to connect, but keep getting the below error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on resource ... on line 17.
```

Here's the code I have currently

```
<?php 
$DB = '//DBGOESHERE:PORT/SIDHERE';
$DB_USER = '****';
$DB_PASS = '****';

$conn = oci_connect($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB);

//check for errors
if (!$conn)
{
    $e = oci_error();
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    exit;
}

$sql = "select display_name, last_export_file, last_export_date from schema.ms_export where last_export_date > sysdate -1 order by last_export_date desc";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
    echo oci_result($stid, 'display_name') . " | ";
    echo oci_result($stid, 'last_export_file') . " | ";
    echo oci_result($stid, 'last_export_date') . "<br>\n";
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Technically I'm trying to get it to output into a pretty HTML table, but starting with cheap and dirty line breaks.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no instance of `query()` in the code you've posted so the problem is not there. Identify line 17 in the correct file and post that code.

Comment: The code I posted is the entirety of the file the fatal error is referencing.  Line 17 would be the $sql line or $stid line I believe. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server at the moment to confirm exactly which one, but I know it's one of those two.

Answer (score 0):

Ends up the above was correct and I hadn't synced the most recent version of the php file. Sorry for the trouble!